# Drupal URL Alias = Broken Links

Tags: url, drupal, url-rewriting

I am currently running Drupal 7.16 and every time I try and set a URL alias when creating a basic page I get a broken link. The link is only the aliased part and therefore an improper URL.

E.g.

What link should look like:
www.example.com/alias_name

What is happening:
/alias_name

When I visit what should be the correct URL I receive a 404 page.

I have searched for a while about this and the only results I find is when people are trying to generate aliases via taxonomy, which I am not trying to do.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Need more information. Can you please provide answers to the following questions? When you type `site.com/alias_name` directly into browser it returns 404 and if you type `site.com/node/123` (the real path of the node) it's OK, am I right? Try to type `site.com/?q=alias_name`, is it still not working? Also, can you check if there is your alias in this listing `admin/config/search/path`. Did you install any custom modules besides Drupal core? Did you edit .htaccess or other system files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put a / on the start of the alias you type.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit embarrassed now :)

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make with a very strange error that results. I can't think why the url alias module lets us do that... It's been a problem since at least D5, maybe earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If you can provide more information or a screenshot, that might be more helpful as this is a little vague.

If you're trying to create an alias when creating a new page, trying using the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module.

If you're trying to add an alias to an existing page, example.com/admin/config/search/path/add, just enter your existing path/node ID and then what you would like the alias to be.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I might have a look at path auto, but I really want to get this fixed. Thank you. Here is a screen shot of how I alias it http://en.yamasakiot.com/1.png and here is how the link ends up when I save the settings http://en.yamasakiot.com/2.png